# Django REST Framework columns with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to serialize data of ManyToMany field. I am having problem in saving the data in ManyToMany field. However, I have found an alternate way but what's the best way to do it?

```
/** Models Code **/
class Layer(models.Model):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

/** In views.py **/
addrole = Layer.objects.create(title=str(key), enabled=True)
addrole.group.add(self.request.POST['group'])
```

Any better way to do it?

Comment: Please suggest a better way to do it. I am stuck in the code.

Comment: If any more clarification needed I will post the other part as well. :(

Comment: Can you add your serializer code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a GroupSerializer:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then in your `LayerSerializer`:

```
class LayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group_set = GroupSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Layer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I am using DRF serializers. I used Model Serializer. How to do it using serializers?

Comment: Changed the answer for DRF.

Comment: This is the right way to do it using many=True. I was missing this in my serializer. Thanks :)